# How should i interpret this grafana visualized prometheus histogram buckets heatmap?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I visualized prometheus histogram buckets as heatmap with grafana, below pic shows the query and the outcome graph, how should i interpret this?

[image]

According to my attacker, in total i sent 300 requests in that period exactly, but when i sum those numbers up on above graph i can never get exact 300,

and also looks those numbers are fluctuating with the time elapsing, how should i interpret this graph in a meaningful way?

And if i want those numbers to be the exact request counts locate in each of those bucket in that time window, what should i do?

Oh, for the `X-Axis` Mode i chose `Series` and the Value i chose `Current`.

Comment: I guess you can't assume that values in prometheus will be 100% correct all the time - https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/#when-does-it-not-fit

Answer (score 4):

There are real reasons why you can't always get a precise rate/increase value out of Prometheus. One of them is failed scrapes, i.e. every now and then a scrape will fail or time out due to a slow service, slow Prometheus or network issue.

The other reason is the fact that collected samples are never exactly `scrape_interval` apart: there will always be a few milliseconds or seconds of delay here and there. So (to take an extreme example) how can you tell the precise increase over the past 1 minute if you only have 2 samples 63 seconds apart? Is it the difference between the two values? Is it that difference adjusted to 60 seconds (i.e. `/ 63 * 60`)?

That being said, Prometheus further boxes itself into a corner by only looking at samples falling strictly within the requested time range. To explain myself: how would a reasonable person calculate the increase of a counter over the last 30 minutes? They would likely take the value of said counter now and the value 30 minutes ago and subtract them. I.e. in PromQL terms (adjusting for counter resets where necessary):

```
request_duration_bucket - request_duration_bucket offset 30m
```

What Prometheus does instead (assuming a `scrape_interval` of `1m` and an ideal timeseries with samples spaced exactly `1m` apart) is essentially this:

```
(request_duration_bucket - request_duration_bucket offset 29m) / 29 * 30
```

I.e. it takes the increase over 29 minutes and extrapolates it to 30. Because of self-imposed limitations, nothing to do with the nature of the problem at hand.

Note that this works fine with counters that increase smoothly and continuously. E.g. if you have a counter that increases by 500 every minute, then taking the increase over 29 minutes and extrapolating to 30 is exactly correct. But for anything that increases in jumps and fits (which is most real-life counters) it will either slightly overestimate the increase if it occurs during the 29 minutes it actually samples (by exactly 1/29) or seriously underestimate it (if the increase occurs in the 1 minute not included in the sampling). This is even worse if you compute a rate/increase over a range covering fewer samples. E.g. if your range only covers 5 samples on average, the overestimate will be 20%, i.e. `1 / (5 - 1)` and (each of) your increases will totally disappear 1 minute out of 5.

The only way I've found to work around this limitation is (again, assuming a `scrape_interval` of `1m`) to reverse engineer Prometheus' extrapolation:

```
increase(request_duration_bucket[31m]) / 31 * 30
```

But this requires you to be aware of your `scrape_interval` and adjust for it and is very brittle (if you ever change your `scrape_interval` all your careful tweaking goes to hell).

Or, if you are OK with your increase falling to zero every time an instance is restarted:

```
clamp_min(request_duration_bucket - request_duration_bucket offset 30m, 0)
```

I do actually have a proposed patch to Prometheus to add `xrate`/`xincrease` functions that actually behave more as you would expect them to (and as described above) but it doesn't look very likely to be accepted: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3806